# Add new field to a collection whose value is from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have 2 collections:

```
notifications:[{
        id: 1,
        eventType:"TRANSACTION"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        eventType:"TRANSFER"
    }
]
```

and

```
events:[{
        id: 1,
        type:"TRANSACTION"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type:"TRANSFER"
    }
]
```

How can I query to update `eventId` field to `notifications` and its value is set with condition `notifications.eventId = events.id where notifications.eventType = events.type'` (`type` is unique)
I tried `aggregate` but it only return the result, not update the collection

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8-RkVX-X7bv

Comment: @chridam i tried this but it only return the result not update. Can you suggest another sollution?/